# How to change font in smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

I have the following code

```
import smtplib

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 

s.starttls() 

s.login("---", "---") 

SUBJECT = "Test"

TEXT = """
Bold Text
Normal Text
"""

message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(SUBJECT, TEXT)

s.sendmail("---", "---", message) 

s.quit()
```

and I would like to make a part of the text bold, and if can, also make it bigger, how can I do this? I checked in some SO questions but, they dont work for me, can someone give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: I think tou will need to send html text to manipulate these things

Comment: But HTML doesn't work :(